# How to load a json file in php code to prepare it for HTTP POST?

Tags: php, xml, json, http-post

I have a .json file on disk. I would like to load it on my php code so that i can make an HTTP POST request with it.

I have done exactly the same with XML like this :

```
$file = 'http://localhost/myServer/test.xml';
$xml_builder = simplexml_load_file($file))
```

Then i use the `$xml_builder` variable to send the XML with CURL.

How can i do *exactly* the same with JSON ?

Comment: Did you even _try_ to look for "json" in the php documentation or on google?

Comment: This is not a concrete programming question, you haven't even written what exactly your question is. We do not know what exactly it means what you've done for in the past XML whatever so that we could tell you anything JSON the same. If you are looking how to read a file, please consult the PHP manual for guidance, it is not necessary to write a question for such a thing here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do something like:

```
$variable = file_get_contents('http://example.com/data.json');
$decoded = json_decode($variable);
```

You need to decode it because you are getting it as a string in the `$variable` and then use it as you want

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$file = '/path/to/json.json';
$json = file_get_contents($file);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

and it will result in an array of your data which you can then use however you want

Comment: Why decode it? I want it to be a json string right? I want to send it as json

Comment: In which case don't use the decode line. Just the first 2

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$url = 'URL GOES HERE';
$file = file_get_contents('http://localhost/myServer/test.xml');

// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'xml' => $file
    )
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

//Print response
print_r('<pre>');
print_r($resp);
die();
```

Comment: added the CURL part of the code, you might need to change/add the fields name into CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to whatever your fields name are for the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
$myJSON = file_get_contents('location/of/your/json');
// $myJSON now contains the JSON string. you can already send this with curl.

$myJSONDecoded = json_decode($myJSON);
// now $myJSONDecoded holds an array with the data. which you can use any way you like.
```